# Target element which content starts-with

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I seem to be having a little issue with some jQuery code but I cant seem to get it to work,
I want to add CSS style **based on the content starting with `1.6`:**

```
<p><strong>1.6.1</strong> this is some content</p>
```

jQuery as follows:

```
$('p strong:starts-with(1.6)').css('background-color', '#3c763d');
```

based on the code it should just style the 'strong' element only.

Comment: sorry i meant jQuery, ill ammend the question now

Comment: @user2513528, consider toggling a class instead of dynamically setting inline styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong...
you *just* need to build your **custom selector extension**:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
  "starts-with" : function(el, i, p, n) {    
     // return el.textContent.startsWith(p[3]); // ES6
     return (el.textContent || el.innerText).indexOf(p[3]) === 0;
  }
});


$('p strong:starts-with(1.6)').css('background-color', '#3c763d');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>1.6.1</strong> this is some content</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

though you already have available the `:contains` selector,
Well, it's **not the same as starts-with**  but is useful in cases

```
$('p strong:contains(1.6)').css('background-color', '#3c763d');
```

where the [Sizzle selector engine](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js) does something already accustomed for the variety of browsers in the wild

```
"contains": markFunction(function( text ) {
  text = text.replace( runescape, funescape );
  return function( elem ) {
    return ( elem.textContent || elem.innerText || getText( elem ) ).indexOf( text ) > -1;
  };
}),
```

Comment: thank you, worked a treat, although i did go for  the `:contains` method, as it worked better

Comment: @user2513528 you're welcome! Just be aware that `strong:contains('1.6')` will also select `<strong>8.1.6</strong>` elements, whether `strong:starts-with('1.6')` will not (since it starts with `8.`)

Comment: thank you for the advice, I'll make the changes, as it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is no jQuery *starts-with* selector for text. You can check that inside **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** -using function as argument, and with regEx, setting the `background-color` only if there's a match.

```
$('p strong').css('background-color', function() {

  if ($(this).text().trim().match("^1.6")) {
    return '#3c763d';
  }
});
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$('p strong').css('background-color', function() {

  if ($(this).text().trim().match("^1.6")) {
    return '#3c763d';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>1.6.0</strong> this is some content</p>
<p><strong>1.6.1</strong> this is some content</p>
<p><strong>2.1.6</strong> this is some content</p>
<p><strong>6.1.6</strong> this is some content</p>
<p><strong>1.6.9</strong> this is some content</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've been looking for a solution like this for like 30 minutes already when I came across yours. You saved my day. :)